# Como criar uma FOREIGN KEY usando uniqueidentifier no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda.

Eu tenho uma tabela no `SQL` chamada Cliente, que tem como chave primaria um tipo `uniqueidentifier`

Ex:

```
Create table Cliente (
    ClienteID uniqueidentifier not null,
    Nome varchar(50)
)
```

Eu gostaria de saber como faço um `FOREIGN KEY` usando o `uniqueidentifier`.

Eu fiz isso mas não deu certo.

```
Create table Locacao (
    LocacaoId uniqueidentifier not null,
    ClienteID uniqueidentifier not null,
);

ALTER TABLE Locacao add constraint FK_Locacao_Cliente_ClienteID FOREIGN KEY(ClienteID) REFERENCES Cliente(ClienteID);
```

Se alguém poder me ajuda eu agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro você deve marcar as suas chaves primárias.

No caso da tabela Cliente, acredito ser o "ClienteId" e no caso da locação acredito ser o "LocacaoId". Depois é só criar a `FOREIGN KEY`

Ficando da seguinte forma o comando:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Locacao]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Locacao_Cliente] FOREIGN KEY([ClienteID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Cliente] ([ClienteID])
```

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou claro a necessidade de uso do tipo **uniqueidentifier** na criação de suas tabelas.

> O tipo de dados uniqueidentifier armazena valores binários de 16 bytes
>   que operam como GUIDs (Globally Unique Identifiers).  Um GUID é um
>   número binário exclusivo; nenhum outro computador no mundo gerará uma
>   duplicata daquele valor GUID.  O principal uso de um GUID é atribuir
>   um indicador que deve ser idêntico em uma rede com vários computadores
>   em muitos sites.
>
> O tipo de dados uniqueidentifier tem as seguintes desvantagens:
>
> - Os valores são longos e obscuros. Isso dificulta a digitação correta dos valores por parte dos usuários.    Além disso, torna-se difícil
>     recordá-los.
> - Os valores são aleatórios e não podem aceitar nenhum padrão que os torne mais significativos para os usuários.
> - Não há nenhuma forma de determinar a seqüência na qual os valores uniqueidentifier foram gerados.    Não são apropriados para os
>     aplicativos já existentes que dependem do incremento dos valores de
>     chave em série.
> - A 16 bytes, o tipo de dados uniqueidentifier é relativamente maior do que outros tipos de dados, como inteiros de 4 bytes.    Isso
>     significa que os índices criados usando chaves uniqueidentifier podem
>     ser relativamente mais lentos do que índices que usam uma chave int.

Se não houver necessidade de uso desse tipo de campo, uma maneira de resolver seria usar o tipo **IDENTITY** e definir as chaves primárias para as duas tabelas.

Ficaria assim:

Create table Cliente (
    ClienteID int primary key identity not null,
    Nome varchar(50)
)

Create table Locacao (
    LocacaoId int primary key identity not null,
    ClienteID int not null,
);

ALTER TABLE Locacao 
ADD constraint FK_Locacao_Cliente_ClienteID FOREIGN KEY(ClienteID) REFERENCES Cliente(ClienteID);

Referência: https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx